# pthread waiting condition does not always wake on signal

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am currently working with condition variables to synchronize two threads (pthreads) and am getting an unexpected behaviour where, even though I have verified a thread is already waiting on a condition, it does not wake when another thread signals on the condition.

It may be worth noting that I have ran this on a desktop environment, and it runs as expected, but this issue arises when I ran the program in an embedded environment using uclibc.

To troubleshoot, I stripped down my code to just the two threads performing lock/unlocking/signalling, which is listed below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condition1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condition2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
bool predicate1 = false;
bool predicate2 = false;

static void * ThreadFunc2(void * arg) {
    sleep(1);    // For testing purposes, ensures this thread is run after Thread1

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        // Do some work - Eg receive some data from a socket
        predicate1 = false;
        pthread_cond_signal(&condition1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

        predicate2 = true;
        while(predicate2 == true)
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition2, &mutex2);

        // Do some more work - Eg send response data to socket
    }
}

static void * ThreadFunc1(void * arg) {
    int result;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1); 
    while(1) {
        predicate1 = true;
        while(predicate1 == true)
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition1, &mutex1);

        // Do some work - Eg process data on the socket and prepare response data to be sent
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
        predicate2 = false;
        pthread_cond_signal(&condition2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread1Id, thread2Id;

    pthread_create(&thread1Id, NULL, ThreadFunc1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2Id, NULL, ThreadFunc2, NULL);

    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I exclude all statements relating to mutex2/condition2/predicate2, the two threads work together as expected.

With the code as listed above, after a short time (since all work has been stripped out, each loop runs very quickly) the wait on condition1 in ThreadFunc1 does not wake even though it is signalled by Threadfunc2 leading to the application being halted.

Also to help me debug, I had redefined the pthread_* functions to print a message to stdout with the matching line numbers prior to calling the actual pthread_* functions. This allowed me to follow the flow of each pthread operation, and verify that the signal was being sent to an already waiting condition.

Can anyone please help me shed some light on any potential issue(s) that may be present from my implementation above?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your example code never sets `predicate2` to `false`.

Comment: I have added the missing predicate2 statement as noted by @caf - Thanks. Unfortunately the issue still remains.

Comment: Can you post the complete test program (it sounds like there shouldn't be a whole lot more), the command used to build the program and info about the platform and tools versions used?  I'm unable to repro with just enough scaffolding added to run the threads and a few `puts()` calls to make sure progress is being made. That's on x86 Linux 3.0 with gcc 4.6.1.

Comment: The code you are showing  **necessarily** runs into a dead-lock (see *gby*'s answer for why). So if your app actually works, the OP's code does **not** represent your app's code ...!

Comment: @alk: There does not seem to be any deadlock there.  `ThreadFunc2` will not be able to acquire `mutex1` until `ThreadFunc1` waits on its condition (and thereby temporarily releases `mutex1`) and vice-versa.

Comment: @wei: Are you initialising the mutexes and condition variables correctly?

Comment: @caf: You are right, it's just a clockwork-alike synchronisation.

Comment: @caf I have edited the source to include the full test source, less printfs which I add at various locations of each thread to try and see what was happening.

Comment: I am beginning to wonder if it is due to the toolchain that was built with my embedded board support package (BSP using buildroot) that is the issue. My platform is m68k-based using uclibc 0.9.31 and gcc 4.4.1. I tested on another older platform (avr32-based using uclibc 0.9.29 and gcc 4.2.1) and the issue was not reproduced.

Comment: @wei: You might be right.  Are you passing the `-pthread` option to `gcc`? (Note: that's `-pthread`, as distinct from `-lpthread`).  If you can reproduce it with the latest version of `uclibc`, you could report it as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar problems. In my case, sometimes the signal was sent before the blocked thread was waiting. The behavior in such case was that both threads were "stuck".
We solved it by adding a flag notifying a signal was sent.

Comment: How did you manage to wake up the waiting thread when it was stuck in pthread_cond_wait? Did you use timedwait instead of wait, and check the flag variable in the same manner as the predicate variables I have used above? Thanks.

Comment: If the flag was set, it did not wait, just continued. In such a way we did not miss the signal.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you do not unlock the mutex used by the condition variable after the calls to  pthread_cond_wait().

e.g pthread_cond_wait() unlocks the mutex internally while the thread is blocked but it re-acquires the lock when it wakes up and you need to explicitly release it.

See this tutorial for more details on cond. variables: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't unlock each mutex after each wait as there are no dependencies on the respective mutex until the loop restarts. From my understanding (which may be incorrect), the only requirement for a wait statement is that the mutex must already be locked by the current thread, which is the case when each thread executes the pthread_cond_wait statement. Are there additional requirements I missed such as requiring the mutex to be released and reacquired prior to a subsequent pthread_cond_wait statement? Thanks.

Comment: There is no need, in the code shown, to unlock those mutexes.

Comment: @wei what keeps the compiler from keeping predicate2 in a register? if you acquire and release the mutex, you would have gone via a compiler memory barrier. I am not sure pthread_cond_wait() is a memory barrier.

Comment: @caf what tells the compiler the value of predicate changes during calls to pthread_cond_wait()? I suspect the usefulness of the mutex ops here are the memory barriers they provide. I am only guessing though.

Comment: @gby: POSIX lists the ["functions that synchronize memory with respect to other threads"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11), which includes the `pthread_cond_wait()` function.

Comment: The discussion here seems to have gone over my head. Am I incorrect in assuming that on switching threads, the context of the current thread is saved somewhere such that upon switching back, the context is restored - ie registers? Is this what is being implied by @gby's reference? If the current thread is scheduled out forcibly by the scheduler (ie. not via the synchronizing functions), is register corruption possible in that case? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I meant @caf's reference in my comment above.

Comment: @wei: The discussion is about *compiler barriers* - in this case, the compiler cannot assume that the value of the predicate variables does not change across the call to `pthread_cond_wait()`, and must reload it from memory each time through the loop (this is the behaviour that you want; the upshot is that your code is OK).

Comment: @wei try setting the predicate2 and predicate1 variables to volatiles. It's a horrible way to force the compiler to not "cache" your variable in a register at all. If that works around your problem I was (probably) right. If it doesn't than the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @caf if I understand correctly what  "functions that synchronize memory with respect to other threads" you are right. I just hope the authors of  whatever pthread library. wei is using got it right as well

Comment: Unfortunately due to time constraints, I have been unable to solve this issue. As a work around, I have restructured my application to not require thread synchronization, and only use mutexes for resource locking which causes the issue to disappear. As stated above, I suspect this issue is due to the toolchain that is being built with my embedded board support package, since all other environments that I had tested on, including a different embedded environment did not exhibit this issue. Thanks again for everyone's valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** - *see explanation below*
Putting pthread_mutex_unlock() before the signaling call pthread_cond_signal() instead of after it should solve the issue

```
...
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
predicate1 = false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
pthread_cond_signal(&condition1);
...
```

in function ThreadFunc2 and similarly for thread 1

```
...
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
predicate2 = true;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
pthread_cond_signal(&condition2);
...
```

in function ThreadFunc1.

**Explanation** In your program thread 2 comes into the signalling call

```
pthread_cond_signal(&condition1); //  thread 2 with mutex1 locked
```

with the mutex1 locked. Thread 1 can only leave the blocking

```
pthread_cond_wait(&mutex1);       //  thread 1 leaves only after mutex1 unlocked
```

call with itself locking mutex1 which is the guaranteed behavior of this function call - that means that it should be unlocked by all other threads in order to continue. If you have an implementation of pthread_cond_signal() that blocks until the thread that receives the signal continues then a dead-lock results when it enters the call with the corresponding mutex locked. That could also explains why one environment could simply work fine while the other doesn't: for instance when your desktop environment doesn't have a blocking call to pthread_cond_signal() while your embedded environment does.

Comment: I've experimented your solution, and it looks it solves an issue I had in a very similar context. The order is really counter-intuitive, though, and the example given in pthread_cond(3) manual page unlocks //after// sending the condition. I'm not totally convinced with your explanation. If it is correct, how

Comment: ... comment continued (5 minutes delay while editing)... So: do you mean that unlock gives immediate control to all threads that wait for lock? Otherwise, putting send after unlock is not guaranteed to change anything. Am I wrong?